# DataFormat for DataGridView dataSource

Tags: c#, data-structures, datagridview

I have data from a CD or Record currently setup like this:

```
class Release       //class containing all details of release
{
    public string Artist;       //Release Artist
    public string Title;        //Release Title
    public string Released;     //Released (Date)
    public Image Image;         //Image

    private List<Track> trackList = new List<Track>();    //List containing tracks
    public List<Track> TrackList
    {
        get
        {
            return trackList;
        }
    }

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Release()
    {
        //Initialize strings to empty strings
        Artist = "";
        Title = "";
        Released = "";
        Image = null;
    }

class Track
{
    public string Position;
    public string Title;
    public string TrackArtist;

    public Track()
    {
        //Initialize strings
        Position = "";
        Title = "";
        TrackArtist = "";
    }

}
```

This works fine as I don't know how many tracks there are when I populate them so I can just add a new item to the list as each one is found.

However I can't work out how to get my Tracklist into the DataGridView without manually populating it cell by cell.

What would be a better way to structure the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz.aspx)

If you don't want to manually set up the Tracklist field binding to the DataGridView control, you could set the AutoGenerateColumns property to True.

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
DataGridView1.DataSource = TrackList
...
```

In the Track class, you might want to set up auto-implemented properties rather than public variables.  For example,

```
class Track
{
    public string Position { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TrackArtist { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear it.  Would you select it as the accepted answer?